# Finite linear quadratic tracking problem using Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimal-control

I'm trying to solve the following linear quadratic tracking problem using Matlab.

The dynamics: $\dot{x}(t) = Ax+Bu$ (scalar system)

The objective function: $J=\frac{1}{2}x(t_{f})^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}[x^{T}(t)Qx(t)+u^{T}(t)Ru(t)] dt$

The goal is to drive $x(t)$ to the desired value $x_d$, i.e., track a constant reference.
I used the algorithm (attached) in the book by Naidu (Optimal Control Systems) and wrote Matlab code to implement it. The differential equations of the Ricatti equations $\dot{p}(t)$ and $\dot{g}(t)$ are solved backwards, and they seem to be correct from the figures. However, the output $x(t)$ does not reach the target $x_d$ (I used $x_d = 3$ as an example). The code is attached.

I would appreciate any help with this matter.

**[The Matlab code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfPMo.png)**

```
clc
close all
clear all
  
% The differential eqn.
% x-dot = Ax+Bu

A   =   -1;
B   =   1;

% objective function matrices (parameters)
Sf  =   1;
Q   =   1;
R   =   1;

E = B*inv(R)*B'; 
C = 1;
W = C'*Q ;
V = C'*Q*C;
xd =3;  % desired value for x

% Finding the dynamic equations for p-dot and g-dot
syms p
syms g

p_dot = -p*A - A'*p + p*E*p-V;
g_dot= -(A-E*p)'*g - W*xd;

 
% initial and final conditions
x0     =   0;      % initial value for x(t)
pf     =   1;      % final value for p(t)
gf     =   Sf*xd;  % final value for g(t)
 
t0      =   0;     
tf      =   2;
 
% solving backwards for the differential Riccati equations p-dot, g-dot
[t,z]=ode45(@lqr_pg, [tf t0], [pf;gf]);

 
% solving forward for the closed-loop state equations ( z=[p;g] )
for j = 1:length(t)
[t1,x]=ode45( @(t,x)sys(t, x, z(j,:)), [t0 tf], x0);
end


% initializing vector u= -Kx+R^-1 B' g(t)   (K=R^-1 * B' * p)
u = zeros(length(t1), size(B,1));
 
for i = 1:length(t)
    uu = -inv(R)*B'*z(i,1)*x(i)+ inv(R)*B'*z(i,2);
    u(i) = uu;
end
 
 
% ploting vector p(t)
figure(1)
plot(t,z(:,1))
ylabel('p(t)')
xlabel('time')

% ploting vector g(t)
figure(2)
plot(t,z(:,2))
ylabel('g(t)')
xlabel('time')
grid

 
figure(3)   % plotting output x(t)
plot(t1,x)
ylabel('x(t)')
xlabel('time')
 
figure(4)   % plotting control u(t)
plot(t1,u)
ylabel('u(t)')
xlabel('time')


% solving p_dot and g_dot, z=[p g]'
function dz=lqr_pg(t,z)
A   =   -1;
B   =   1;
R   =   1;
W   =   1;
E = B*inv(R)*B'; 
xd  = 3;  % desired value for x

z1dot = z(1)^2+2*z(1)-1;              % z(1) is p
z2dot = -(A-E*z(1))'*z(2) - W*xd;     % z(2) is g

dz  =   [z1dot; z2dot];
end


function xdot = sys(~, x, z)
    A   =   -1;
    B   =   1;
    R   =   1;
    E = B*inv(R)*B'; 
    xdot = (A-E*z(:,1))*x+E*z(:,2);
end
```

[Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfPMo.png)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way Matlab code is displayed. Is there a better way to include it?